# Cache web page on Android's default browser.

Tags: android, url, caching, browser

I have an android application that has a changing list of urls. I wish to cache the web pages that the urls point to in the device's default browser, without opening them. The user would then click on links within the app, and even when the device can't connect to the internet, the urls can be opened in the device's default browser. Is this possible?